# Estimate number of lunches eaten

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

Consider a hotel that serves lunch to its customers. Each day, some customers will arrive and some will leave such that in each day there are 100 customers in the hotel. About 80% of the customers have lunch at the hotel.

Every customer has a equal probability (1/7) of leaving in any of the 7 days that follow the check in. Also, if a customer has lunch after the check in, he will have lunch every day for the whole stay and if the customer doesn't have lunch on the first day, he won't ever have lunch. On the day that the customer leaves, he doesn't have lunch.

The task is, given a n-day history of the number of lunches prepared, to estimate the number of lunches required on the following day.

My initial approach was to create a probability mass function that determines the number of people leaving/staying on day n. The problem is that I have some issues adding the probability of eating lunch and consider also the number of lunches on the previous day.

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag and see its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)